# using bash with sed how to extract ip from a hostname command and saving it in /etc/hosts file

Tags: bash, sed, hostname, hosts-file

I want to store an entry in the **/etc/hosts** file for the IP of the box that I am on.

When I run the following command I get:

```
:-$ hostname
ip-10-55-9-102
```

I want to store this entry in /etc/hosts as following:

Expected result: `10.55.9.102   ip-10-55-9-102`

I tried but so far....

CURRENT SOLUTION:

```
ip=$(hostname -I | cut -d ' ' -f1); echo "$ip ip-${ip//+([.:])/-}" >> /etc/hosts
```

Actual result: `10.55.9.102   ip-10.55.9.102`

Note: Expected has "-" and Actual has "." between numbers.

Comment: @Aserre the second part.... one has "-" and other has "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is good, but you don't use the correct pattern in your string substitution. You should have written the following :

```
ip=$(hostname -I | cut -d ' ' -f1); echo "$ip ip-${ip//[.:]/-}" >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using *awk*?

```
hostname | awk -F- '{printf "%s.%s.%s.%s %s\n", $2, $3, $4, $5, $0}' >> /etc/hosts
```

The awk command uses the `-F-` flag to specify the dash as a field separator. The `printf` command picks out fields #2, 3, 4, 5, along with $0 which is the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

With plain `bash`:

```
ip=$(hostname -I)
ip=${ip%%[[:space:]]*}
printf "%s\tip-%s\n" "$ip" "${ip//./-}" # >> /etc/hosts
```

Drop the `#` if it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system var `$HOSTNAME` which is the same as `hostname` command. So if your hostname contain an ip address you can do this:

```
ip=${HOSTNAME//ip-} # create 'ip' var from $HOSTNAME and remove 'ip-'
ip=${ip//-/.}       # change '-' to '.' in 'ip' var
printf "$ip\t$HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts # add desired string to /etc/hosts
```

Or using `hostname` to get ip:

```
ip=( $(hostname -I) )
printf "$ip\t$HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts
```